# How to call undirectly to Key of an Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Object with two Keys (persons) that have theirs own arrays/ I would like to access those arrays (one by one) without calling the Key name directly / like this: obj.key.

```
const obj = {
 viktor: ['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'],
 kate: ['grape', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana'],
 };
const PersonsArr = Object.keys(obj);
const Viktor = personsArr[0]

console.log(obj.Viktor)
//Undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.values(obj).forEach( array => console.log(array));
```

if you would like to get a specific one, key is needed